# Not able to click link using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to open a page and click on a link which opens a modal asking for the username. After entering the username it asks for the password.

I am new to selenium and am trying to get familiar with browser automation.

The website is http://mumbai.quikr.com/

On the right side there is the option to login/register which open a modal.

My code is below which I have tried to adapt after watching a youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--vqRAkcWoM.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/dabangg/Downloads/python/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32/geckodriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("http://mumbai.quikr.com/")

def test_Login(self):
    driver =self.driver


  #  loginLink = "//input[@value='Log In']"
   # loginLink="submit"
   # loginLink="(//a[contains(@id,'loginLink')])[1]"
  #  loginLink = "(//a[contains(@href,'javascript:')])[1]"
    loginLink = '//*[@id=\'loginLink\']/'


    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginLink))


    loginButtonElement.click()


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have tried to locate the element using `class/id/xpath` but none of them work. Using span I was able to locate the element but then I got a message saying the element is not interactable.

Also, on another not can someone please help me difference or uses of below

1. Requests
2. Beautiful soup
3. selenium

and which one is better to use/learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate required element by `linkText` and wait until it becomes clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link_text = "Login/Register"
loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, link_text)))
loginButtonElement.click()
```

Note that there is extra slash after predicate in your locator `'//*[@id=\'loginLink\']/'`. Try to remove that slash (`'//*[@id=\'loginLink\']'`) to make your locator valid

Comment: ERROR: test_Login (__main__.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\basicactionsselenium-quikr.py", line 30, in test_Login
    loginButtonElement.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute

Comment: return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

Comment: I am able to run the code now but I when it opens the browser it is not clicking on the login link to open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I am normally using C# but what seems to be causing the problem is that you are using an id and in the code you call it xpath:

> find_element_by_xpath(loginLink))

should probably be find_element_by_id(loginLink))
In C# I would have wrapped the Id in quotes, but I don't know for you if that works like that.

If you find element by xpath like you did than use this find_element_by_xpath(.//*[@id='loginLink']/span)  ...and yet watch out for the quotes as in my language we treat it as a string so I don't know what works for you

Comment: In context of `find_element_by_xpath(loginLink))` `loginLink` is not an `id`, but a variable with `XPath` expression

Comment: I have got the xpath using the firepath addon of mozilla

Comment: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

Answer (score -1):

I simply added a sleep command and it is working now. below is the code:

## https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--vqRAkcWoM

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import unittest
import time

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/dabangg/Downloads/python/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32/geckodriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("http://mumbai.quikr.com/")

def test_Login(self):
    driver =self.driver
   
 
  #  loginLink = "//input[@value='Log In']"
   # loginLink="submit"
   # loginLink="(//a[contains(@id,'loginLink')])[1]"
  #  loginLink = "(//a[contains(@href,'javascript:')])[1]"
    loginLink = ".//*[@id='loginLink']/span"

 
    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginLink))
    time.sleep(5)

       
    loginButtonElement.click()
    time.sleep(5)
 

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```